# Calculate Bootstrap's column height and center child with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple jQuery function that will callculate parent's height and vertically align the the child inside of the parent without using css. Image height will change (so column height also) when user changes the browser width.

Here is my code

```
$('.valign').each(function() {
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var topmargin = (parentHeight - thisHeight) / 2;
    $(this).css("margin-top", topmargin);
});
```

... and my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="image-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="valign">VERTICALLY CENTERED TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks functional. Your question is how to pass this into a function?

Answer (score 0):

Your parents height will not be the tallest in the list of elements with a class of `.col-sm-6` div elements.

You will need to go over all columns and get the one with the maximum height value, then add this value to all other columns. Using CSS you can force the child elements to have a `vertical-alignment` of `middle` with `display: table-cell`, only on screens bigger than `750px`.

Also make sure for the image to be loaded, otherwise you will not get the max height value.

Here is an example, sure you will get the idea.

```js
var maxHeight = 0;

$(window).load(function() {

  $('.valign').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
  });

  $('.valign').height(maxHeight);

});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");


@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .valign > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 valign">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 valign">
      <div>VERTICALLY CENTERED TEXT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```